# Merge 2 Classes dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda, func

I have two classes implementing the same interface. One of these two classes has more properties than the other one. Now I'm looking for a solution to fill the class with the fewer properties in the greater one.

Actually I might use a manually mapper. I know but this must work for every class which called this function. I have read that a `lambda expression` could be my solution but I don't know how I can write this generically and dynamically for every interface/class.

My question is to not create a new instance but use an existing instance. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Use reflection to run through the properties of the "small" type. For each one, find the property with the same name on the "large" type. Read from your instance of the large type, and write to a new instance of the small type.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using a third party tool, [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) does the thing rather well.

Example taken from AutoMapper documentation :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>();
OrderDto dto = Mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do mind using a third party tool, you can use this snippet and adapt as needed:

```
public B Convert<A, B>(A element) where B : A, new()
{
    //get the interface's properties that implement both a getter and a setter
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(A)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(property => property.CanRead && property.CanWrite).ToList();

    //create new object
    B b = new B();

    //copy the property values to the new object
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        //read value
        object value = property.GetValue(element);

        //set value
        property.SetValue(b, value);
    }

    return b;
}
```

Comment: For exampl if `B` does not actually derive from `A`, then he can keep the names of the properties and check that the other type also has a property by that name.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen That's true. The code assumes that both classes implement the same interface, as pointed out by OP. Further validation could be added, depending on the exact use case for this.

Comment: Or: `public void Copy<T>(T from, T to) where T : class
{
    /*get the interface's properties that implement both a getter and a setter*/
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(property => property.CanRead && property.CanWrite).ToList();

    /*copy the property values to the new object*/
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        /*read value*/
        object value = property.GetValue(from);

        /*set value*/
        property.SetValue(to, value);
    }
}`. Use like: `var b = new B(); Copy<ITheInterface>(element, b);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void BusinessObjectConverter<TTarget, TSource>(this TTarget target, TSource source)
    {
        //Lesen aller Properties auf der ersten Ebene
        var targetProperties = typeof(TTarget)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
            .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite);

        //Lesen aller Properties auf der ersten Ebene
        var sourceProperties = typeof(TTarget)
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
            .Where(prop => prop.CanWrite);

        //Loop durch alle Properties
        foreach (var item in targetProperties.Intersect(sourceProperties))
        {
            //Leere Werte duerfen nicht geschrieben werden
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(source.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(source, null).ToString()))
            {
                //Befuellen der Properties im Zielobjekt
                item.SetValue(target, ValueConverter.ConvertValue(
                    source.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(source, null),
                    item.PropertyType),
                    null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would be working for me...
It extends the objects and i can update the fields to write in database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to add comments due to low rep so will have to post an answer.

Following on from the Automapper answer, it can be a pain to manually create the mappings. To do it dynamically I use:

```
TDestination destination = new TDestination();            
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source, destination, opts => opts.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
```

All you have to remember to do is to make sure the property names match